Variable "is not defined" error even though it is defined
I'm doing the python mega course on udemy, and I get an error.
I get an error even though I did exactly what the instructor did. It is supposed to show all your todo items when you type "show" but it gives an error. Here's the code:
prompt = "Type  add, show, edit, complete or exit: "

while True:
    user_action = input(prompt)
    user_action = user_action.strip()
    match user_action:
        case 'add':
            todo = input("Enter a todo:") + '\n'

            file = open('../todos.txt', 'r')
            todos = file.readlines()
            file.close()

            todos.append(todo)

            file = open('../todos.txt', 'w')
            file.writelines(todos)
            file.close()

            new_todos = []

            for item in todos:
                new_item = item.strip('\n')
                new_todos.append(new_item)
        case 'show' | 'display':
            file = open('../todos.txt', 'r')
            todos = file.readlines()
            for index, item in enumerate(new_todos):
                item = item.title()
                row = f"{index + 1}-{item}"
                print(row)
        case 'edit':
            number = int(input("Number of the to do to edit:"))
            number = number - 1
            new_todo = input("Enter new todo:")
            todos[number] = new_todo
        case'complete':
            number = int(input("Number of the to do to complete:"))
            todos.pop(number - 1)
        case 'exit':
            break

print("Bye!")

And here's the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python Programing - Ardit\Python Programs 2024\app1\pythonProject\files\main.py", line 28, in <module>
    for index, item in enumerate(new_todos):
                                 ^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'new_todos' is not defined

It says that "new_todos" isn't defined, but looking at the code it is.

Hi Nathan, can you explain better your problem. Send a more complete and organized snippet code.

I will edit it so the thing has the full code, thank you

I think you want enumerate(todos) instead in the show option. Otherwise, why are you reading a file?

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to write a title that summarizes your problem, thinking on future users that may have a similar issue. Check [ask] and how to format.

new_todos is defined inside the "add" case, but you're trying to access it from the "show" | "display" case. You need to define it outside the switch, assuming the rest of the code is correct.

@SimonMᶜKenzie case blocks don't have separate scope, do they?

Oh, sorry @JohnGordon . I'm a C# developer!

new_todos is defined only when the case 'add' block has executed.
If the case 'show' | 'display' block is executed before that, the variable will indeed be undefined.
So, the user must have typed "show" or "display" first, before they typed "add".
You can fix this by moving the line new_todos = [] to the very top of the code, so it is always executed.

The variable isn't really needed, though. It's the same as todos, just with new lines removed which could also be handled in the show case by looping over the todos list extracted there
